# URL filtering , issues with URL

Tags: networking, http, redirect

I am working on a URL filtering project . I have a database given to me which contain URLs need to be blocked (eg: a.b.com/d/e).

I get uri and domain from http request. I compare what I get with my database and redirect users without any problem. So far so good.

Problems starts with urls that contains query string and other magics with URL. As an example if user enters a.b.com/d/e?junk. What I get won't match with my database, and users will bypass my filter and they will still be able to go a.b.com/d/e.

I tried some useless actions like slicing everything after special chars like "?,#". But having problems with url like :  youtube.com/watch?v=12vh55_1ul8, which becames like youtube.com/watch and blocks all youtube. That solution causes me more problems.

Now I am very confused how to handle this problem. Is there any guide or any library which I can use in C++ ?

Comment: So you want to allow access to only certain YouTube videos?

Comment: Youtube was just an example. My client wants to block any url they want. Without blocking whole domain. An example is blocking : a.com/b/c/index.html but not whole a.com . 'a', 'b' ,'c' could be any string here youtube, facebook, adultsite etc...

Comment: You would need to add the key=value to the blocked database just as you have with the hostname.com/path. You can then disregard any junk data, and only search for host&&path&&key=value. Hashes can most likely be ignored as they mainly exists for client side functionality. 

This is a programming question though, and is better suited for StackOverlow.com

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I didn't understand what key=value will be composed of. Can you give an example.

Comment: if(host=="youtube.com"&&path=="/watch"&&param[v]=="12vh55_1ul8") { blocked(); }

Comment: Thanks a lot seem very reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 string str (get_requsted_uri());
 string str2 ("http://getaroundfilters.com/article/889/proxy");

 if (str.find(str2) != string::npos) {
 block();
 } else {
 get_and_return_webpage(str);
 }
```